# Can I SELECT all the bult-in functions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to display every built-in function (like LEFT, SIN, IIF etc.) with a query?

Comment: You should be specific to your requirement, what is your use case?

Comment: I don't think that SQL Server surfaces this information within the database.

Comment: @SurajKumar simple curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation or syntax highlighting definition from official tool:

[Azure Data Studio - syntax support](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/blob/main/extensions/sql/syntaxes/sql.tmLanguage.json)

```
{
"match": "(?i)\\b(avg|checksum_agg|count|count_big|grouping|grouping_id|max|min|sum|stdev|stdevp|var|varp)\\b",
"name": "support.function.aggregate.sql"
},
{
"match": "(?i)\\b(cast|convert|parse|try_cast|try_convert|try_parse)\\b",
"name": "support.function.conversion.sql"
},  ...
```

Searching for: **"name": "support.function**

---

Idea - Not tested: Maybe it is possible to extract that data from system database - *Resource*

> [Resource Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/resource-database?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> The Resource database is a read-only database that contains all the system objects that are included with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

No, the [functions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/functions) is your best alternative. It gives a structured overview of all supported built-in functions.

Using any decent IDE will provide some highlighting and auto-completion features for function names.